# "Remove personal information" default save in Office for Mac 2011?

Tags: ms-office

Is anyone aware of a way of setting Office for Mac 2011 to automatically use the "remove personal information" option on every save?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can see of doing this is to modify or create a new blank template with the setting baked in.

1. File -> New From Template -> Blank
   Document
2. Make Privacy changes as
   before
3. Save as Word Template (This will normally appear under my Templates, but I presume you could overwrite the existing Blank template, wherever it is located).
4. Then when creating a new document, use the new template you created.

Jonathan